# sqlite3_prepare_v2 statement is not SQLITE_OK and I don't know why

Tags: iphone, objective-c, if-statement, sqlite

I have this code in my viewWillAppear method:

```
 sqlite3 *database;
if (sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database)
    != SQLITE_OK) { 

    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
}
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

//why is this if statement failing?
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement UTF8String],
                       -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
```

It passes the first if statement without entering (which is good).  The 2nd if statement is the problem.

The sqlStatement is in the form of SELECT * FROM food WHERE foodType = 'fruit'
I don't understand why it's not getting into the if statement.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to do more investigation before we can help. What is `sqlite3_prepare_v2` actually returning, rather than just not `SQLITE_OK`? What does `sqlite3_errmsg` say? I could ask additional questions (What's your schema? Does your SQL include a trailing semicolon? What threading model are you using?), but those are stabs in the dark without more information. It's very likely you'll figure this out when you do that investigation.

Comment: sqlite_prepare_v2 is returning 1, and the sqlite3_errmsg just says no such table: fruits.  however, I know the table is there.  This problem has been stumping me

Comment: Have you verified the table with the sqlite3 command line tool?

Comment: The SELECT you give as example reads data from *food* and you say you have an error about table *fruits*. Make sure you don't have a problem with foods and fruits :-)

Comment: Why are you writing SQLite by hand at all?  Waste of time.  Use Core Data or, at the least, something like FMDB.

Comment: I wrote my own SQLite wrapper, and I agree with @bbum. It's crazy at this point to write your own SQLite wrapper (I wrote mine years ago). It's even crazier to try to use the sqlite3 C API directly from your code.

Comment: @stevenFisher Whoops.  I meant to write no such table: foods.  And the reason I'm using SQLite is to get used to it because they do it this way at my work.  But I will keep that in mind as I program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up not being in the code, but in the way that I exported the sqlite file.  It was a series on INSERT statements, not an actual table.

Answer (score 0):

and make changes according to ur requirement...

```
-(void) readDataFromDatabase
{
    chapterAry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"QuotesApp.sqlite"];

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sqlStatement ="select * from MsExcelTutorial";

        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSNumber *chapterId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0)];

                NSString *chapter = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];

                NSString *link = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

                NSString *bookmark = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];

                NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:chapterId,@"chapterId",chapter,@"chapter",link,@"link",bookmark,@"bookmark", nil];

                [chapterAry addObject:dic];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *DBPath = [ClsCommonFunctions GetDatabasePath];
if ([self OpenDBWithPath:DBPath])//Method to open database connection
{
//filesDB is database object 
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    const char *sqlStatement = "select fileID,filePath from tblFiles where  isUploadPending =1";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(filesDB, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
        {
            // u Need to get data from database...                


        }
    }
    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    sqlite3_close(filesDB);
}
```

go through it it will work